# Microstrategy URL API

Tags: java, greenplum, microstrategy

Reading from this [link](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/_CurrentGARelease/docs/projects/WebSDK/Content/topics/scenarios/WEBSDK074.htm), [link](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/GARelease_Current/docs/projects/WebSDK/Content/topics/scenarios/MicroStrategy_URL_Parameters.htm), [link](http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.co.id/2012/01/url-api-hacks-for-microstrategy.html), [link](http://bipostit.com/en/2016/10/01/microstrategy-personalizar-ejecutaciones-de-informesdocumentos-y-responder-prompts-via-api-url/), [link](http://www.bryanbrandow.com/2011/08/answering-prompts-via-url-api.html) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28042855/1533670) about Microstrategy URL API, I want to pass the answer to one or more prompts in the request to that the report document is executed automatically without requiring the user to enter information.

When I tried to use `valuePromptAnswer` method for multiple prompt, Microstrategy only take the first argument. The other argument doensn't works. Here are the URL

```
http://111.222.333.444/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=******&Project=*****&Port=0&evt=4001&src=mstrWeb.4001&reportID=226F3C76422512B0E56995939C230DF1&visMode=0&reportViewMode=1&valuePromptAnswers=12^11
```

The microstrategy only takes the first argument.

Using `elementsPromptAnswers` generate the same result, only the first prompt receive the value

```
http://111.222.333.444/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=****&Project=***&Port=0&evt=4001&src=mstrWeb.4001&reportID=226F3C76422512B0E56995939C230DF1&visMode=0&reportViewMode=1&elementsPromptAnswers=F9365CA24CFDFD394F3D01ACB4EA5F21:1;474209F94C5C6140979F31848D01E40F:2
```

Using `objectPromptAnswer` generate the same result

```
http://111.222.333.444/MicroStrategy/servlet/mstrWeb?Server=****&Project=****&Port=0&evt=4001&src=mstrWeb.4001&reportID=226F3C76422512B0E56995939C230DF1&visMode=0&reportViewMode=1&objectsPromptAnswers=474209F94C5C6140979F31848D01E40F~12~DistChl
```

I've read the documentation carefully for each step by step. What I'm missed out? Is there any configuration on server side to accept all argument / parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you try the first example, the one with value prompts, are both prompts in your report value prompts?

Answer (score 0):

We had did the thing you talk about using the next url:

```
mstrWeb?port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=YOURDOCUMENTID&valuePromptAnswers={&Prompt1&}^{&Prompt2&}^{&Prompt3&}^{&Prompt4&}^{&Prompt5&}^{&Prompt6&}&promptAnswerMode=2
```

In the previous example, {&Prompt1&}, {&Prompt2&}, etc. are responses of a previous prompt. In your case, the url to create should be the next url:

```
mstrWeb?port=0&evt=2048001&src=mstrWeb.2048001&documentID=226F3C76422512B0E56995939C230DF1&valuePromptAnswers=12^11&promptAnswerMode=2
```

I think that your problem could be on the **evt** or **promptAnswerMode** parameters, because if these are not correctly configured it can get in troubles.

Hope that this answer solves your problem.
Greetings.